# What is the code for a T-SQL check constraint?

Tags: t-sql

I want to add a check clause to this table so that:

IF a transaction enters a value for the diastolicBloodPressure

THEN the transaction must also insert a value for the systolicBloodPressure.

```
CREATE TABLE "Constraint-BloodPressure".Patient
(
    patientNr int NOT NULL,
    diastolicBloodPressure smallint,
    systolicBloodPressure smallint,
    CONSTRAINT Patient_PK PRIMARY KEY(patientNr)
)
```

**Is this correct?**

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_BloodPressure CHECK (diastolicBloodPressure >0 AND systolicBloodPressure >0 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what database system you are using. On SQL Server 2014 I am require specify "NULL" or "NOT NULL". So my create table statement with the check constraint and insert statements looks like this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Patient', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Patient;

CREATE TABLE #Patient
(
    patientNr INT NOT NULL
  , diastolicBloodPressure SMALLINT NULL
  , systolicBloodPressure SMALLINT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT Patient_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (patientNr)
  , CHECK ((
               diastolicBloodPressure IS NOT NULL
               AND systolicBloodPressure IS NOT NULL
           )
           OR (
                  diastolicBloodPressure IS NULL
                  AND systolicBloodPressure IS NULL
              )
          )
);

INSERT INTO #Patient VALUES (1, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO #Patient VALUES (2, 120, NULL);
INSERT INTO #Patient VALUES (3, NULL, 80);
INSERT INTO #Patient VALUES (4, 120, 80);
```

The first and last insert statements work and the middle two fail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
 Yes folks - Mea culpa!  I should use NOT NULL.
However, my focus is on the check clause. 
I want to specify the rules that make our modeling tool generate an "appropriate" check clause from what we call an "Equality Constraint". Right now I'm trying to figure out the rules for generating an equality constraint between two or more columns in a single table.  (Later I'll have to figure out how to do it across two or more tables. )
You have all been a great help. Thanks

Comment: @KenEvans Please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you, to say *You have all been a great help*, But: This comment below Isaac's answer will not reach anybody else. I just came back by chance... The SO way to say thank you is an upvote and the acceptance of the answer you like most.

Comment: @Isaac, Btw: It is a very bad habit to create a CONSTRAINT without a name. This will be created with a random name. Just imagine, that you might have to change this constraint in 250 customer#s databases and everywhere the name differs...

Comment: @Shnugo Point well taken.

Comment: @Shnugo  - Thanks for your guidance. Each of the answers is helpful in its own way.  So I liked all of them!

Comment: @KenEvans, That's perfectly okay, thank you. Just pick one, which ever you think helps you most, and cklick the acceptance check (the check below an answer's vote counter). This will close the answer and following users will have it easier to find their solution. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify, whether your table would accept NULL-values and how you would deal with them.

Due to the kind of data, my suggestion was this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestCheck
(
     patientNr INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_TestCheck PRIMARY KEY
    ,diastolicBloodPressure smallint NOT NULL
    ,systolicBloodPressure smallint NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT chk_TestCheck_MustEnterBoth CHECK(diastolicBloodPressure BETWEEN 0 AND 250 AND systolicBloodPressure BETWEEN 0 AND 250)
);
```

--The table will not accept NULL-values and it will force the entered values to keep within realistic borders.
--Instead of `smallint` you might use `tinyint`, which is bordered between 0 and 255 by definition.

--Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestCheck VALUES(1,100,110);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TestCheck VALUES(2,100,NULL);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TestCheck VALUES(3,NULL,NULL);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TestCheck VALUES(4,-1,1000);
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestCheck;
```

--Only the first insert will succeed, all the other attempts fill fail
--Clean-Up Carefull with real data...

```
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestCheck;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force both fields to have a value, then you need to check for null values.  If you don't, then your current check will allow entry of just the patientNbr or just one value.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Patient
(
    patientNr int NOT NULL,
    diastolicBloodPressure smallint,
    systolicBloodPressure smallint,
    CONSTRAINT Patient_PK PRIMARY KEY(patientNr),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_BloodPressure CHECK (ISNULL(diastolicBloodPressure, 0) > 0 AND ISNULL(systolicBloodPressure, 0) > 0 )
);
GO

-- Valid
INSERT INTO dbo.Patient VALUES (1, 120, 80);
GO
-- Invalid
INSERT INTO dbo.Patient VALUES (2, 120, 0);
GO
-- Invalid
INSERT INTO dbo.Patient VALUES (3, 0, 80);
GO
-- Invalid
INSERT INTO dbo.Patient (patientNr, diastolicBloodPressure) VALUES (4, 120);
GO
-- Invalid
INSERT INTO dbo.Patient (patientNr) VALUES (5);
GO
```